# Xcode 8 distorting and stretching image in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, xcode8

Added 3 PNG files to the Xcode image assets folder (@1x, @2x, @3x). When using the images to add a button to Interface Builder, it appears distorted **only in Interface Builder**.

This worked fine in Xcode 7. Does anyone know there any specific that I need to do to fix this issue?

Here are my slicing settings for the image asset for the @1x file. The @2x and @3x are at 12 and 18 for each value, respectively.

[image: Xcode 8 Image Slicing Settings]

Here is what the user sees:

[image: iPhone Simulator Button]

Here is what is displayed in Interface Builder:

[image: Interface Builder Button]

I have a specific height and width for the constraints of the image (in this instance, height = 44, width = 130) and whenever I turn off horizontal and vertical slicing, the stretching seems to stop in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a well-established bug in Interface Builder (I reported it in 2013!). As you rightly say, the problem comes and goes to varying degrees in different versions of Xcode. But it doesn't affect what happens at runtime, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was informed by Apple Developer Relations that as of Xcode 8.3 beta 3, this issue has been fixed. I opened my project and confirmed that the issue seems to be resolved. I'll keep people posted if anything changes.