# Xcode 10 Interface Builder stretches images

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, xcode10

Just updated Xcode to 10.0 and here we go - all my button background images are stretched in the Interface Builder (when building and running the app, everything is fine). I know in the past that was a common Xcode bug, but it was reported that this was resolved as of Xcode 8.3: [Xcode 8 distorting and stretching image in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433693/xcode-8-distorting-and-stretching-image-in-interface-builder)

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix this now? Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing this problem in Xcode 10.1, I briefly tried the 10.2 beta and it seems to be fixed there.